# Math Calculator without 2 operands in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, math, visual-c++

The value starts from 0 and can then be calculated using any operand of Mathematics. The code compiles successfully but doesn't work. The terminal windows shows 'Abort', 'Retry' and 'Cancel'. The rule is that you cannot use 2 operands but just keep adding the previous number to present operand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void Input(double input);

int main()
{
    double sign, input;

    cout << "This program calculates any given number upto 1 decimal place using the following operators:" << endl;
    cout << " '+' - Addition." << endl;
    cout << " '-' - Subtraction" << endl;
    cout << " '*' - Multiplication." << endl;
    cout << " '^' - Root." << endl;
    cout << " '/' - Division." << endl;

    Input(input);

    return 0;
}

void Input(double IN)
{
    char q;
    char sign;
    int Val = 0.0;

    cin >> sign >> IN;

    while (IN != q)
    {

        if (sign = '-')
            Val -= IN;
        if (sign = '+')
            Val += IN;
        if (sign = '*')
            Val *= IN;
        if (sign = '/')
            Val /= IN;

        cout << endl << "Result so far is " << IN;

        IN++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend that you clearly specify what is giving you trouble. I can see one repeated error in the code that could be the issue, but I'd rather have fixed goalposts.

Comment: The program doesn't work, I want to calculate the number according to which operation sign is provided to calculate.

Comment: Where does it not work? What line/ expression? What does it do instead of what you want it to do?

Comment: It compiles successfully but doesn't work. It says "Run-Time Check Failure #3-T"

Comment: Have you resolved all of the compiler warnings? Compiler warnings are important messages from the compiler that your logic may not be sound even if the syntax is correct.

Comment: Yes! The is no compiler warning.

Comment: Interesting. What compiler?

Comment: Visual Studio v2015

Comment: On the main menu select Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General and set "Warning Level" to Level3 or higher. You should get much better diagnostics. Actually go for Warning Level 4. The compiler should tell you pretty much everything that's wrong at that level.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Out of general interest, what was the warning level set to?

Comment: Level 4. I got an error now, int "Val" gives an error saying " expression must be a modifiable Ivalue"

Comment: I must have different code from you at this point. I don't see that at all.

Comment: What you should have gotten is a bunch of uninitialized variables (source of the original error you reported. Don't use a variable before you set it to something) , `double` to `int` truncation warnings, and a batch of "assignment within conditional expression" warnings.

Comment: You are passing a **copy** of the `IN` variable to your `Input` function.  The original variable from `main` will not be modified.  Pass by reference if you want the parameter to be modified in the caller's function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is

1. `q` is undefined so the `while(IN != q)` will become undefined behavior
2. in `C++`, for any primitive datatype `=` means assignment operator, and not a comparator operator. To compare something use `==` instead.
3. `Val` is a variable with `int` datatype but assigned with value `0.0` which is a float or double.

What your program do in the if statement is : (for example this `if` statement)

> `if (sign = '-')`

1. The program assign the value of `-` which is `45` to the `sign` variable
2. The `if` statement check the variable `sign` for value `0`

   - if the value is `0` then the statement considered `false` and the block is skipped
   - if the value is other than `0` then the statement considered `true` and enter the block
3. The program run the code inside the `if` block

The program do all of those 3 thing for every `if` statement in your code, and I rarely run my own code in `Windows` so I can't very sure why the program giving the `Run-Time Check Failure #3-T` error

A little advice, use `switch` whenever you need to use multiple `if` statement, since it is easier to read.

Comment: Worth an edit to add that `Val` is an integer and is throwing away any computed fractions and that `IN` accomplishes nothing as a parameter.

Comment: "Run-Time Check Failure #3-T" is almost certainly Visual Studio stopping the program when `input` is used uninitialized in `main` or `q` is used uninitialized in `Input`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for reminding, how could I overlook such a simple datatype error. But `Val` as a integer and being assigned with `/=` is not a major concern for me, since I am not fully understand what is the original intention of the program, and I just pointed out some easy to miss mistake, and using `IN` as function argument without any true argument also not a big deal since it is more about "how to write a proper code" instead of "how to write a working code" (since sometime I use a disposable argument to select which function for function overloading).

Comment: @user4581301 also if my understanding is correct, then is `Run-Time Check Failure #3-T` basically a build in undefined behavior checker by VS? If so then it's pretty neat to have a build in Undefined Behavior checker

Comment: Visual Studio's debug builds have a wide variety of checks and tweaks  intended to make the world safer from bad code. They can't get everything, but they work pretty well.